# Does Hebrew שׁלום have the connotation of death?

Tags: hebrew, cultural-analysis, shalom

Albright (1931) notes two possible etymologies for the name of the Semitic god Šulmân ([*The Syro-Mesopotamian God Šulmân-Ešmûn and Related Figures*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41662002). Archiv für Orientforschung. p. 168):

> The appellation *Šulmânu* "god of welfare", may be explained either as being a euphemistic designation for the god of the underworld, *URU-SILIM-MA* (cf. *šalâm šamši*, "end", i.e., "death of the sun, sunset", and Arabic salîm, "dead", Acc. *šalamtu*, "corpse"), or as indicating his function as the divine healer.

Does Hebrew שׁלום, like the cognates listed there, have a connotation of "death" as well?

I found five occurrences of שׁלום where such a connotation may be present: Genesis 15:15, Psalms 4:8, Proverbs 3:2, Isaiah 57:2 and Jeremiah 34:5. However, none of these verses is truly problematic *without* assuming this connotation.

Is it valid to attribute the notion of "death" to this Hebrew word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that the Hebrew שׁלום is related with a 'death' concept.

Likely, the Akkadian term 'šalamtu' was a derivation from a metathesized root, SML,'to cover' > 'to cloth','to dress' (from which derived [?] SMLE we found in Gen 9:23 ['garment'], onward. Please compare also the Italian term 'salma' ['corpse'], since the dead bodies - a well-known procedure - were wrapped up in a garment, or bandages. As far as I know, the hebrew root abovementioned is not related with a 'death' concept, also in the verses you cited, like Psa 4:8, Pro 3:2, and Isa 57:2.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a reference for the etymology of Akkadian *šalamtu*?

Comment: The reference about the Akkadian term you ask for is: 'The Assyrian Dictionary of the Oriental Institute of the University of Chicago' [CAD], vol XVII, pages 203-206, "_corpse, from O[ld] B[abylonian] on_ [...]."